# Remove , from all integers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

All integers are by default delimited by `','` .

For ex: 123456 is shown as 1,23,456.

Is there a way to remove `','` from all integers for all tables.

If it is for a single table and a particular field, we can do in the following way in its controller.

`config.columns[:<int_field>].options={:i18n_options => {delimiter: ""}}`

Is there a way to do this for all integer fields?

PS: Using Activescaffolding in my application.

Thanks.

Comment: Stored as in stored in DB? DB doesn't have delimiter while storing as integer.

Comment: Seems like it's because of I18n. Are you sure it's saved like that in database

Comment: Oops! You are correct @Victor.
It's not being stored in DB with ','. It's just being displayed in the application that way.

Comment: @Mounika Then check if the view uses this helper - `number_with_delimiter`. If it uses, then remove it to remove the `,`.

Comment: @Victor I use activescaffolding. So, I don't have separate views for the tables. Looks like activescaffold will provide it by default. https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API:-Column#options

Answer (score 2):

Use `tr` as:-

```
2.0.0-p645 :005 > "1,23,456".tr(',', '')
=> "123456"
```

Convert the result to integer as:-

```
2.0.0-p645 :005 > "1,23,456".tr(',', '').to_i
=> 123456
```

Check methods in string in `irb` as:-

```
"".methods
```

Use it in view as:-

```
<%= "1,23,456".tr(',', '').to_i %>
```

For more details [see the document](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/tr)

Comment: I don't have separate views for the tables as I use  activescaffolding. Is there any other way which don't involve views?

Answer (score 0):

I assume Rails with Activescaffold uses formatting rules from its I18n module by default. You can change them in `config/locales/en-US.yml`. [Here is the default one with the relevant lines highlighted](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-US.yml#L164-L169).

This should affect all formatting of numbers in views. I think you just have to change the delimiter to a blank string:

```
...
format:
  delimiter: ""
...
```

You can find general information about Rails I18n in the corresponding [I18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: Sounds correct. Not sure why it is not working for me. I just now found an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly.

Added the following lines in application_helper.rb:

```
def format_number_value(value, delimiter = '')
  if value.is_a? Integer
     ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_delimited(value, delimiter: '')
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think this will override Activescaffolds own `format_number_value`: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_scaffold/3.4.37/ActiveScaffold%2FHelpers%2FListColumnHelpers%3Aformat_number_value Be careful! Your implementation is not compatible (yours accepts different parameters).